# How to mark a whole assembly as non parallelizable in NUnit 3?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nunit

We have a whole assembly that we would like to mark as  non parallelizable in NUnit.

I've found that there is a `[NonParallelizable]` that according to [the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NonParallelizable-Attribute) can be set to the assembly level. But where should I put it?

Does anybody has an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply the attribute to the assembly you should specify its target (MSDN [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#using-attributes)) - by using `assembly:` - so you should have:

```
[assembly: NonParallelizable]
```

This attribute can be put in any file in the assembly as long as it's not be inside a namespace, but typically the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is used for assembly attributes.

For whatever reason the NUnit documentation that you linked to doesn't provide any sample attribute usages, but the [source for `NonParallelizableAttribute.cs`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/NonParallelizableAttribute.cs) shows there is a parameterless constructor (which I used above).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no `[Parallelizable]` attributes in the assembly, then the assembly is non-parallelizable. Adding a `[NonParallelizable]` attribute at the assembly level serves only as documentation in this case.

`[NonParallelizable]` at the assembly level **does not** override any lower-level `[Parallelizable]` attributes you may have in the assembly. On the contrary, the lower level attributes override the higher level one.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I triple checked, I've no references at all to Parallelizable in this assembly(I've in 2 other assemblies), but I was getting errors saying that the ScenarioContext.Current was used in a multithreaded environment by tests in this assembly.